# Unable to install kali-linux-default package for kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, installation

I am unable to install the kali-linux-default package on my kali linux. When I run the command it incurs the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ettercap-graphical : Depends: ettercap-common (= 1:0.8.3.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
 kali-linux-default : Depends: kali-linux-headless but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: kali-tools-top10 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: autopsy but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: cutycapt but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: dirbuster but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: faraday but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: fern-wifi-cracker but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: guymager but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: hydra-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: king-phisher but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: legion but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: ophcrack but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: ophcrack-cli but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: starkiller but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: zaproxy but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: cherrytree but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: gparted but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: rdesktop but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: recordmydesktop but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: sqlitebrowser but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: tightvncserver but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: xtightvncviewer but it is not going to be installed
 set : Depends: ettercap-common but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: python3-impacket but it is not going to be installed
```

When I enter the command `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, it returns errors below:

```
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar{.zst,.lz4,.gz,.xz,.bz2,.lzma,}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/ettercap-common_1%3a0.8.3.1-3_amd64.deb
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar{.zst,.lz4,.gz,.xz,.bz2,.lzma,}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-impacket_0.9.22-1_all.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: '/var/cache/apt/archives/ettercap-common_1%3a0.8.3.1-3_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ettercap-common_1%3a0.8.3.1-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: '/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-impacket_0.9.22-1_all.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-impacket_0.9.22-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ettercap-common_1%3a0.8.3.1-3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-impacket_0.9.22-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried the command  `sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends`, but it seems to not working as well:

```
dpkg: ettercap-graphical: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 ettercap-graphical depends on ettercap-common (= 1:0.8.3.1-3); however:
  Package ettercap-common is not installed.

Setting up ettercap-graphical (1:0.8.3.1-3) ...
dpkg: set: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 set depends on ettercap-common; however:
  Package ettercap-common is not installed.
 set depends on python3-impacket; however:
  Package python3-impacket is not installed.

Setting up set (8.0.3+git20200609-0kali2) ...
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/usr/share/set/src/fasttrack/exploits/firefox_3_6_16.py'
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/usr/share/set/src/payloads/set_payloads/multi_pyinjector.py'
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/usr/share/set/src/payloads/set_payloads/shell.py'
dpkg: error processing package set (--configure):
 installed set package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: kali-tools-exploitation: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 kali-tools-exploitation depends on set; however:
  Package set is not configured yet.

Setting up kali-tools-exploitation (2021.2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 set
```

I have run out of methods but still have no clue how to solve the problem so I am desperately in need for help.

Comment: Try the following:  sudo apt-get update followed by sudo apt-get full-upgrade . I think that should get the remaining packages.

Comment: @john, that will most likely break his already @#$&ed up installation. I mean... Lol It is already broken. He hasn't included what version this actually is either. IDK why people don't just format with a newer version honestly, the full-upgrade & dist-upgrade can take longer than a new install. (If it doesn't just break the installation).